# How to optimize SQL query and return count using inner join and subquery

Tags: mysql

We are getting result proper but its taking too much time to execute.Can we optimise query which will take less time to execute.

```
SELECT c.client_id
FROM client_master c
INNER JOIN user_visit_record u ON u.client_id = c.client_id
WHERE c.dept_id ='1'
  AND c.branch_id='1'
  AND c.client_status IN('Hot','Warm','Cold','Quotation')
  AND u.next_followup_date < '2017-06-01'
  AND u.visit_id IN
    (SELECT max(visit_id)
     FROM user_visit_record
     WHERE client_id=c.client_id)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check indexes for visit_id field and client_id.

Comment: We didnt used indexing

Comment: Probably you get lot more speed if you create indexes for the relevant columns.

Comment: how can we do indexing in this query..can you please send.?

Comment: Index are at table level, not query level. You need to create index on the table. Example: CREATE INDEX user_visit_record_ix ON user_visit_record (visit_id);. For more info, check mysql manual for indexes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the optimized query:**

```
SELECT c.client_id 
FROM client_master c 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM user_visit_record u ORDER BY u.visit_id DESC) AS t ON t.client_id = c.client_id 
WHERE c.dept_id ='1'   
AND c.branch_id='1'   
AND c.client_status IN('Hot','Warm','Cold','Quotation')   
AND t.next_followup_date < '2017-06-01' 
GROUP BY t.clientid
```

Comment: Thanks You @Kruti Patel ..But this query retrieves wrong result.

Comment: Can we get another solutions for this.??

Answer (score 0):

I have Used * in query, you can do is select only required columns,one way of optimising

And MySQL has several existing solutions, check this [Article](http://www.cocomore.com/blog/mysql-query-optimization)

```
SELECT c.client_id
    FROM 
        (SELECT *
        FROM client_master
        WHERE dept_id ='1'
                AND branch_id='1'
                AND IN('Hot','Warm','Cold','Quotation')) AS c
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT *
        FROM user_visit_record
        WHERE next_followup_date < '2017-06-01'
                AND visit_id IN 
            (SELECT max(visit_id)
            FROM user_visit_record
            WHERE client_id=c.client_id)) AS u
            ON u.client_id = c.client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT client_id FROM 
  (
    SELECT client_id 
      FROM client_master 
        WHERE dept_id ='1' AND branch_id='1' AND client_status IN('Hot','Warm','Cold','Quotation')
  ) AS c

  NATURAL JOIN

  (
    SELECT client_id
      FROM user_visit_record 
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT client_id, max(visit_id) as max_visit 
            FROM user_visit_record
              GROUP BY client_id
        ) AS max_user_visit 
            ON (user_visit_record.client_id = max_user_visit.client_id) 
              AND (user_visit_record.visit_id = max_visit)
        WHERE next_followup_date < '2017-06-01'
  ) AS u
```